# How/why is it that a periodic function or signal can be split into a series of sinusoids?

Tags: intuition, mathematical-physics, math-history, mathematical-modeling, fourier-transform

The basis of Fourier transformation is the concept that any periodic signal can be broken into frequency and amplitude varying sinusoid's which on adding give the original signal. I find this difficult to digest as I have recently been introduced to Fourier theory. Is there any proof (preferably mathematical) that prove this statement?

Comment: It is not true that the Fourier series converges to the original function at all points. it depends on what you mean by equal. There are various sufficient conditions for convergence, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence for example.

Comment: @user102958 Look at their link. It's definitely not true. However, if the Fourier transform has bounded support, you do get a nice result. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Answer (score 3):

For most "reasonable" practical purposes, it is indeed true that the Fourier series "represents" the original function. But/and this requires making "reasonable" and "represents" sufficiently precise. For example, for most continuous functions, the Fourier series fails to converge pointwise to the pointwise values of the original function at many, many points. But we might object that "pointwise values" (at, for example, countably-many points) are not reasonable, in the same way that in real life we cannot measure temperature "at a point", but only on a small region of space. Still, from a neo-platonic mathematical viewpoint, it is arguably of interest (if not "reasonable") to wonder about point-wise values, and much has been written about this.

Pointwise convergence for fairly nice functions was proven c. 1830 by Dirichlet, and perhaps earlier by Fourier in a manuscript that was lost or delayed.

Apart from technicalities about pointwise convergence, we *do* have $L^2$ convergence, also called "mean-square".

Apart from specific details of convergence, yes, it is fairly remarkable that every periodic function can be represented as a sum of some "basic" periodic functions. This theme was further taken up by Sturm and Liouville in the 1830's, with details fleshed out only in the 1890s by Steklov and Bocher, under the umbrella of "eigenfunction expansions".

Proofs of various of these things are too long to include here, I think, but can be found many places on the internet. (E.g., my notes http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/)

Comment: I think I remember hearing that those reviewing Fourier's paper found this representation a little *too* remarkable, and were reluctant to give their seal of approval.

Comment: @pjs36, yes, in particular, at first he did not have the inner-product formula for the coefficients, but apparently for the moment just "predicted" that there should be coefficients... which was not so convincing, because then it was not testable in any way.

Comment: I had no idea! The account or two I had read made it sound like the Royal Academy was just too stodgy or something... that's a pretty significant problem.